# Which to use method of Google Maps SDK like struct MKCoordinateRegion of MapKit

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, mapkit

I rework [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/73984/make-app-like-runkeeper-part-1#comments) for Google Maps SDK for iOS. I want define it by supplying a center point and a span that defines horizontal and vertical ranges.
I read [this tutorial of Google Maps SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_camera_position) I think that should to use `zoomAtCoordinate:forMeters:perPoints:` It's not quite right, in my point

```
    func mapRegion() -> MKCoordinateRegion {
        var region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0, 0), span: MKCoordinateSpanMake(0, 0))
        var initialLoc: Location = self.trek.locations.firstObject as! Location
var minLat = (initialLoc as Location).latitude.doubleValue
        var minLng = (initialLoc as Location).longitude.doubleValue
        var maxLat = (initialLoc as Location).latitude.doubleValue
        var maxLng = (initialLoc as Location).longitude.doubleValue

        for location in self.trek.locations.array {
            if (location as! Location).latitude.doubleValue < minLat {
                minLat = (location as! Location).latitude.doubleValue;
            }
            if (location as! Location).longitude.doubleValue < minLng {
                minLng = (location as! Location).longitude.doubleValue;
            }
            if (location as! Location).latitude.doubleValue > maxLat {
                maxLat = (location as! Location).latitude.doubleValue;
            }
            if (location as! Location).longitude.doubleValue > maxLng {
                maxLng = (location as! Location).longitude.doubleValue;
            }
        }

        region.center.latitude = (minLat + maxLat) / 2.0;
        region.center.longitude = (minLng + maxLng) / 2.0;

        region.span.latitudeDelta = (maxLat - minLat) * 1.1; // 10% padding
        region.span.longitudeDelta = (maxLng - minLng) * 1.1; // 10% padding

        return region;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `GMSCoordinateBounds`

```
func mapRegion() -> GMSCoordinateBounds {
        var path = GMSMutablePath()
        var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(path: path)
        var initialLoc: Location = self.trek.locations.firstObject as! Location    
        var minLat = (initialLoc as Location).latitude.doubleValue
        var minLng = (initialLoc as Location).longitude.doubleValue
        var maxLat = (initialLoc as Location).latitude.doubleValue
        var maxLng = (initialLoc as Location).longitude.doubleValue      
        for location in self.trek.locations.array {
            if (location as! Location).latitude.doubleValue < minLat {
                minLat = (location as! Location).latitude.doubleValue;
            }
            if (location as! Location).longitude.doubleValue < minLng {
                minLng = (location as! Location).longitude.doubleValue;
            }
            if (location as! Location).latitude.doubleValue > maxLat {
                maxLat = (location as! Location).latitude.doubleValue;
            }
            if (location as! Location).longitude.doubleValue > maxLng {
                maxLng = (location as! Location).longitude.doubleValue;
            }
        }       
        path.addCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(minLat, minLng))
        path.addCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(maxLat, maxLng)) 
        return bounds;
    }   
self.viewMap?.animateWithCameraUpdate(GMSCameraUpdate.fitBounds(mapRegion(), withPadding: 15.0))
```